# Terminal command 'login' fails with error message

Tags: command-line, login

Coming from Mac OS X, there is a possibility for every ordinary user to open Terminal and type in 'login' to change to a different user account.

When I do this with Ubuntu, it provides the following error message:

```
login: Cannot possibly work without effective root
```

Is there any way to remedy this?  Which file do I need to edit and with what to enable the use of this command (even for a standard user)?

Comment: For changing to other user account you can use `su username` command.

Comment: `su <username> -` - note the hyphen.

Comment: Thanks @run and muru  That kinda works and is even shorter than "login".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `su <user name>` for changing to a different user.

Answer (score 0):

The `login` command in Ubuntu requires root permissions. Try `$ sudo login`.